# MySQL: Ordering sets of ordered rows without dividing sets

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table with *entry_id* and *edit_date* columns. What query should I use to order by *edit_date* sets of rows which are grouped by *entry_id*? Group by not in SQL terms.

Now I'll try to clear up waht i want:

What I have

```
entry_id    number
Entry 1 19
Entry 1 10
Entry 1 80
Entry 2 60
Entry 3 83
Entry 4 73
Entry 5 15
Entry 2 26
Entry 2 9
Entry 2 5
Entry 3 95
Entry 2 57
Entry 3 4
Entry 4 88
Entry 2 39
Entry 3 78
Entry 3 4
```

What I need:

```
entry_id    number
Entry 3 95  <- biggest in set
Entry 3 83  
Entry 3 78  
Entry 3 4   
Entry 3 4   
Entry 4 88  <- biggest in set
Entry 4 73  
Entry 1 80  <- biggest in set
Entry 1 19  
Entry 1 10  
Entry 2 60  <- biggest in set
Entry 2 57  
Entry 2 39  
Entry 2 26  
Entry 2 9   
Entry 2 5   
Entry 5 15
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ORDER BY entry_id, number DESC`

Comment: @ElGavilan thanks, but priority should be given to _number_ row. In your case it would be ignored unless _entry_id_ are the same.

Comment: You want the number row sorted in descending order grouped by entry_id, yeah? That will give you exactly what you are asking for. [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d5845/1)

Comment: No @ElGavilan Have a close look at the result set.

Comment: Unless I'm not reading it right, it looks like you want `number` sorted in descending order for each entry_id. So all of entry_id '3' together, sorted by `number` in descending order. That is what the example that I gave does. Are you looking for something different? Can you clarify exactly how you want your result set to look?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the result would be to include a derived "biggest in set" column.

If you had a resultset like this:

```
_id number biggest
3   95     95
3   83     95
3   78     95
3   4      95
3   4      95
4   88     88
4   73     88 
1   80     80
1   19     80
1   10     80
2   60     60
2   57     60
2   39     60
2   26     60
```

You could then `ORDER BY biggest DESC, _id DESC, number DESC`

One way to get the "biggest in set" would be to use a query with a `MAX(number)` aggregate function and a `GROUP BY _id`, and use that query as an inline view, and do a join operation. For example:

```
SELECT t._id
     , t.number
  FROM mytable t
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT m._id
              , MAX(m.number) AS biggest
           FROM mytable m
          GROUP BY m._id
       ) b
    ON b._id = t._id
 ORDER BY b.biggest DESC, t._id DESC, t.number DESC
```

The inline view query **`b`** returns the "biggest in set" number for each `_id`.

Answer (score -1):

`ORDER BY entry_id, number DESC` will sort `number` in descending order, grouped by `entry_id`. `entry_id` will also be sorted.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d5845/1)